# Detect and Delete date string in a text

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

i want know if it's possible detect and delete a date in string format in a text, like this:

```
Title 31 December 2012
Title December 2012
Title 31-12-12
Title (31-12-12)
```

in this three example in all cases i want delete all and remain only the world "Title", i found this method for example to delete the text inside the parentheses:

```
 searchText = [searchText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" \\([^()]*\\)" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
```

and i can delete this (31-12-12), but i can't understand how i can do for the other cases...

Comment: Is Title always the first thing? Could you always just set the value of searchText to @"Title"? The string replacement you posted uses regex to replace the string matching characters with empty strings, so you would need to determine the regex combinations for all possible scenarios.

Comment: no the title it's only for example, change always...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a different regex.

This one should catch all your 4 cases.

```
searchText = [searchText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\W+((\\(?\\d+(-|\\.)\\d+(-|\\.)\\d+\\)?)|((\\d+ )?\\w+ \\d+))" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
```

Comment: I edited my answer, but being more specific wouldn't hurt. Doesn't work in which way? In which cases?

Comment: thank you very very much, now works! :) very last question there is a way do fix also this: Title - First Edition - 31 December, and remain only this: Title - First Edition? thank you again for the amazing answer :)

Comment: can you tell me also how i can find a documentation to use this? because i think in future i have to add more cases and i want do it myself :)

Comment: My last edit catches that case too. Look for any regular expressions guide. To try them out I would advise http://rubular.com/. Also remember that you need to escape `\` in your Obj-C string.

Comment: in this way this is not fixed: "Title - May 2012" return "Title - "

Answer (score 2):

Combine into one RE:

```
NSString *reText = @" ((\\d{2} )?\\w+ \\d{4})|(\\(?\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\)?)";
```

Note that this is really comprised of two REs or'ed together:

`(\\d{2} )?\\w+ \\d{4}`
and
`\\(?\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\)?`

See [NSRegularExpression Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
NSArray *testList = @[
    @"Title 31 December 2012",
    @"Title December 2012",
    @"Title 31-12-12",
    @"Title (31-12-12)"
];
NSString *reText = @"( (\\d{2} )?\\w+ \\d{4})|( \\(?\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\)?)";

for (NSString *test in testList) {
    NSString *result = [test
                        stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:reText
                        withString:@""
                        options:NSRegularExpressionSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
                        range:NSMakeRange(0, [test length])];
    NSLog(@"result: '%@' test: '%@'", result, test);
}
```

NSLog output:
result: 'Title' test: 'Title 31 December 2012'
result: 'Title' test: 'Title December 2012'
result: 'Title' test: 'Title 31-12-12'
result: 'Title' test: 'Title (31-12-12)'